# Exclude tags from tag cloud in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

So I have 2 different group of tags in one post, let's call them list A and B. List A is the tag cloud for the entire site. List B contains the tags or the keywords related to the post. Now, some of the words in list B are repeated in list A. I am trying to figure out a way where the words in list B aren't repeated in list A (the tag cloud). Is there an easy way to do that. I am new to all of this, so I would appreciate your help.

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud('smallest=10&largest=10&format=flat&unit=px&separator=, &exclude=<?php the_tags();>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to embed a php tag into a single quoted string. You can't do that, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

You can do this though:

```
$args = array(
    'smallest' => 10,
    'largest' => 10,
    'format' => 'flat',
    'unit' => 'px',
    'separator' => ',',
    'exclude' => 'cats,dogs');
wp_tag_cloud($args);
```

`the_tags()` will echo, you'd want to use [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) instead.